# Compare string with wildcard string

Tags: c#, strings, array

I have the following function to compare a string with a wildcard string (containing ? and *), as C# doesn't seem to have a builtin function to do it.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Compares wildcard to string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="WildString">String to compare</param>
    /// <param name="Mask">Wildcard mask (ex: *.jpg)</param>
    /// <returns>True if match found</returns>
    public static bool CompareWildcard(string WildString, string Mask, bool IgnoreCase = true)
    {
        int i = 0, k = 0;

        // Cannot continue with Mask empty
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Mask))
            return false;

        // If WildString is null -> make it an empty string
        if (WildString == null)
            WildString = string.Empty;

        // If Mask is * and WildString isn't empty -> return true
        if (string.Compare(Mask, "*") == 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(WildString))
            return true;

        // If Mask is ? and WildString length is 1 -> return true
        if (string.Compare(Mask, "?") == 0 && WildString.Length == 1)
            return true;

        // If WildString and Mask match -> no need to go any further
        if (string.Compare(WildString, Mask, IgnoreCase) == 0)
            return true;

        while (k != WildString.Length)
        {
            switch (Mask[i])
            {
                case '*':

                    if ((i + 1) == Mask.Length)
                        return true;

                    while (k != WildString.Length)
                    {
                        if (CompareWildcard(WildString.Substring(k + 1), Mask.Substring(i + 1), IgnoreCase))
                            return true;

                        k += 1;
                    }

                    return false;

                case '?':

                    break;

                default:

                    if (IgnoreCase == false && WildString[k] != Mask[i])
                        return false;

                    if (IgnoreCase && Char.ToLower(WildString[k]) != Char.ToLower(Mask[i]))
                        return false;

                    break;
            }

            i += 1;
            k += 1;
        }

        if (k == WildString.Length)
        {
            if (i == Mask.Length || Mask[i] == '*')
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I added the check to make sure `Mask` isn't null/empty because if it is then `switch (Mask[i])` will throw a `IndexOutOfRangeException`. I'm wondering if there are any other checks I should make or change (specifically during the `while` loop)?

Comment: why dont you use Regex and you save yourself this hassle http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11556/Converting-Wildcards-to-Regexes

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I want a foolproof method rather then something that has unknown problems with it

Comment: Why do you think that the $Regex$ method "has unknown problems"? What would satisfy you that any solution was "foolproof"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do is called "globbing". [It's actually quite easy to do with a `Regex`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188892/glob-pattern-matching-in-net)

There are a few code smells here. The recursion is the obvious one. The other is the special-cases. When you special-case the single-character wildcard, it suggests that you're thinking about the problem wrong. There's no reason why they would need to -- or even should -- be specialcased.

If you really want to reinvent the wheel, the "right way" is to build a state machine <strike>and backtrack</strike>. I combined @NotPro's answer and @svick's hint to get http://ideone.com/VUDFIw but that uses backtracking. Check out http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html to see why backtracking is a bad idea, and how we can get an O(n) state machine.

Answer (score 7):

Another option, as outlined in this [blog](http://www.henrikbrinch.dk/Blog/2012/02/14/Wildcard-matching-in-C) is to not re-invent the wheel and use the VB.net `LikeString` method:

Add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` first.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;

if(Operators.LikeString("This is just a test", "*just*", CompareMethod.Text))
{
  Console.WriteLine("This matched!");
}
```

Comment: `using Microsoft.VisualBasic` in a C# project? o.O

Answer (score 1):

You still have bug for `wildString = "xyzz", mask = "?"` .

The best idea is to use `Regex` but if you want implement your own solution I would use `Linq`. I think it's make solution much shorter and easier to understand.

```
static bool CompareWildcard(IEnumerable<char> input, string mask)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mask.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (mask[i])
        {
            case '?':
                if (!input.Any())
                    return false;

                input = input.Skip(1);
                break;
            case '*':
                while (input.Any() && !CompareWildcard(input, mask.Substring(i + 1)))
                    input = input.Skip(1);
                break;
            default:
                if (!input.Any() || input.First() != mask[i])
                    return false;

                input = input.Skip(1);
                break;
        }
    }

    return ! input.Any(); 
}
```

Comment: @Snowbody You're right that using `Skip()` this way is a bad idea (it leads to \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ code), but how exactly do you clone `Enumerator`? A better way to do this might be to use [`ImmutableStack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467197) or [`FSharpList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370372.aspx).

Comment: @svick Yikes! I committed the cardinal sin of C#, assuming that it worked the same as C++. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: @Snowbody Now that I think about it, if `input` was `string`, then its enumerator is [`CharEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.charenumerator), which can be cloned. But you can't do that with a general `IEnumerator<char>`.